# PostgreSQLの障害ケースについて

Tags: postgresql

PostgreSQL 15.3について学んでいます。Oracle専門でやってきていたので、PostgreSQLではどのような障害パターンが起こりやすいものなのか想像しづらい部分がありますので教えてください。現在私は、バックアップ／リカバリ方法について学んでいるところです。

1. pg_dumpとpsql

最初にこれを覚えました。OracleでいえばDataPumpに似ていると思いました。論理レベルでデータを退避させておいて、何かあったらpsqlコマンドで戻すことになるわけですね？バックアップ／リストアと言えなくもないですが、単純なエクスポート／インポートに思えます。データ移行にはよいかもしれませんが、psqlコマンドでダンプをインポートするまでの間、更新があったらどうリカバリしたらよいのでしょうか？また、戻さなければいけないデータが存在しながらも、消したくない更新データが入ってきてしまっていたとしたら、ダンプをインポートすることで消してしまう恐れはありませんか？

2. pg_basebackup

実行して驚きましたが、cpコマンドでコピーを取っただけのようなデータベースクラスタの物理的なコピーが作成されました。つまり、このコマンドで取得したバックアップを使う時となると、OSコマンドで物理的にファイルやディレクトリを削除したとか、そんな感じのときでしょうか？

3. recovery.conf

私がネットで拝見する記事が古いのでよくこのファイルが登場しますが、これは現在のpostgresql.confファイルのrestore_commandパラメータに該当すると考えてよいですか？例えば、データベースクラスタの中身をOSコマンドで全削除されて(なかなかあり得ない)、pg_basebackupコマンドで取得しておいた物理ファイル、ディレクトリをリストアしました。そうしたら、restore_commandをちゃんと設定していれば、DB再起動とともにアーカイブログが適用されていくみたいな仕組みですか？

Answer (score 2):

> pg_dumpとpsql
> バックアップ／リストアと言えなくもないですが、単純なエクスポート／インポートに思えます。データ移行にはよいかもしれませんが、psqlコマンドでダンプをインポートするまでの間、更新があったらどうリカバリしたらよいのでしょうか？また、戻さなければいけないデータが存在しながらも、消したくない更新データが入ってきてしまっていたとしたら、ダンプをインポートすることで消してしまう恐れはありませんか？

逆に疑問なのですが、Oracleはそういう都合のいい処理をよしなにしてくれるのでしょうか。ダンプ(いわゆる論理バックアップ)からの復旧でそんなことが自然にできるはず、とは普通は考えないと思います。あなたが(勝手に)想定したシナリオに適合しないからといってバックアップではないということにはなりません。目的に対して誤った手段を選択している方の問題です。

> pg_basebackup
> 実行して驚きましたが、cpコマンドでコピーを取っただけのようなデータベースクラスタの物理的なコピーが作成されました。つまり、このコマンドで取得したバックアップを使う時となると、OSコマンドで物理的にファイルやディレクトリを削除したとか、そんな感じのときでしょうか？

逆になぜそういう特化した状況でしか使えないと思ってしまったのかが不思議です。誤削除からのリストアに使えるのであれば、大抵のシナリオでもリストアに使えると考えるのが普通だと思いますが。

> recovery.conf
> 私がネットで拝見する記事が古いのでよくこのファイルが登場しますが、これは現在のpostgresql.confファイルのrestore_commandパラメータに該当すると考えてよいですか？

正確には、recovery.confが廃止されてその設定項目が本体に移動したという話です。

> 例えば、データベースクラスタの中身をOSコマンドで全削除されて(なかなかあり得ない)、

pg_basebackupのところに書いたとおり、なぜこういう限定された状況しか出てこないのかが不思議です。

> pg_basebackupコマンドで取得しておいた物理ファイル、ディレクトリをリストアしました。そうしたら、restore_commandをちゃんと設定していれば、DB再起動とともにアーカイブログが適用されていくみたいな仕組みですか？

前提として`archive_command`でWALがアーカイブされていることが必要です。障害でWALが失われているのに`restore_command`を指定しても無意味です。

WALが保存されていれば、`restore_command`を使用せずに別途データディレクトリにコピーすることでリストアすることもできます。

前後しますが、こういう疑問を持たれた根本は

> Oracle専門でやってきていた

とかPostgreSQLの知識不足ではなくて、バックアップ&リストアについての一般的な考え方がどこかずれてることのような気がします。

Comment: すみません。まだPostgreSQLのアーキテクチャについて知識が未熟なため、その点はご容赦ください。まず、pg_dump/psqlは、Oracleで言えばData Pumpユーティリティを使用した論理レベルのデータバックアップに似ている。しかしこれをバックアップと言うなら、リストアしてもバックアップを取得した時点のデータが戻されるだけというのはOracleも同じです。私の調べ方に問題がある可能性はじゅうぶん自覚した上で、それでもポスグレのバックアップでググっているとやたらpg_dumpコマンドの使用が出てくるので、これはバックアップ/リストアツールとしてどうなんでしょう？という疑問を投げかけさせて頂きました。

Comment: pd_dumpは、バックアップツールというより、サーバに静止点を設けた上で論理レベルのバックアップだけをエクスポートする移行ツールでしょうと理解しています。次にpg_basebackupですが、Oracleではソフトウェアのインストールディレクトリとデータファイルの格納場所が分離されており、バックアップも、バックアップセットやイメージコピーという独自の形式で取得します。

Comment: その上で、Oracleではデータファイル等々に破損や障害が発生すればアーカイブログを当てつつ完全リカバリを行います。とりあえずポスグレにはOracleでいう表領域やデータファイルという概念、物理ファイルが存在しないことは理解していますが（合っていますか？）、インストールディレクトリ（ポスグレで言うデータベースクラスタ）の丸ごとバックアップを取って、一体それはどのような障害発生時にどのようにリストアするの？と思いました。WALファイルパラメータはreplicaに設定し、WALアーカイブはデータベースクラスタ外のディレクトリに吐くようにしています。

Comment: タイトルで、PostgreSQLの障害パターンと掲げていながら、PostgreSQLのネイティブ機能に対してああだこうだ書いてしまったので、話が拡がりすぎました。このようなことが起こる可能性があるから、このようなツールを使ってバックアップを取っておいて、このように対処すればいいみたいに教えて頂けると幸いです。

Comment: 質問に関わる情報はコメント欄で続けるのではなく、質問文を直接編集して見直してください。タイトルも「〜について」のような曖昧な表現てばなく、何を知りたいのか・分からないのかを端的に言い切るべきです。